# Pre-loading assembly doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, assembly-loading

I am writing a test to check that all the controllers in my Unity config are registered correctly. As part of my test, I use reflection to check for all the non-abstract classes that inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`. However, I consistent get a `System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException`. I find this strange for two reasons:

1. I have a using statement at the top of my file that should cause this particular assembly to load automatically when the test is run.
2. I also attempted pre-loading the assembly.

My code is:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Unity;

namespace Presentation.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnityTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void UnityRegistration_ControllersInitialize()
        {
            // Initialize the container the same way we do in the code
            // but make sure that the container is disconnected from the application
            // so we don't accidentally change runtime behavior through testing
            var container = UnityRegistration.Initialize(new UnityContainer());

            // Get all the controllers in the presentation layer so we can check whether or not
            // they can all be constructed at runtime
            Assembly.Load("System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35");
            var assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad("Presentation, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
            var ctrls = assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (Controller)) && !t.IsAbstract && t.IsClass);

            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var ctrl in ctrls)
            {
                // Check resolution on each type. If resolution fails or
                // the result is null then we should record the error
                bool isErr;
                try
                {
                    var obj = container.Resolve(ctrl);
                    isErr = obj == null;
                }
                catch
                {
                    isErr = true;
                }

                if (isErr)
                {
                    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Controller of type {0} could not be resolved.", ctrl.Name));
                }
            }

            string errors = builder.ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(errors))
            {
                Assert.Fail(errors);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the reference to `Controller` here refers specifically to `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`.

The exception that was thrown had no inner exception and a large number of loader exceptions, which all stated `Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.`

Could someone please explain why pre-loading doesn't seem to be working in this manner and how I would properly ensure that the proper assemblies are loaded?

Comment: Only a `using` statement won't trigger the loading of an assembly you have to actually use it or it will be optimized out. You can register the `AssemblyResolveEvent` and look at what events it tries to resolve. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve

Comment: What exactly do you mean "I also attempted pre-loading the assembly" ?

Comment: `ReflectionTypeLoadException`, what are the loader exceptions and inner exception?

Comment: Additionally the method `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad` requires the `FullName` of an `Assemlby` and your input `Presentation` doesn't seem to be a `FullName` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyload#System_Reflection_Assembly_ReflectionOnlyLoad_System_String_

Comment: @JohnWu I mean that I attempted to fix the issue by calling `Assembly.Load` with the full name of the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly as an argument, which as I understand, is pre-loading it.

Comment: @JSteward I have added exception details

Comment: @RandRandom I'm not sure I follow. When I call `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad`, I can still get information on the assembly. Wouldn't it return null if I didn't provide enough information to load it?

Comment: @RandRandom Also, I am referencing the `Controller` object on the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly. Is that not considered "using" it?

Comment: @RandRandom I changed my code to use `Presentation`'s full name but that hasn't had any affect on the exception.

Comment: There are other App Domain events, which you can review to check what's happening while you are trying to load assembly / Resolve Type, that would provide more information

Comment: There's another way, SimpleInjector provides an inbuilt Verification mechanism to verify the DI configurations in a Test setup, check [this](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html), **Verify the container’s configuration**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Microsoft [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-load-assemblies-into-the-reflection-only-context):

> The reflection-only load context allows you to examine assemblies
>   compiled for other platforms or for other versions of the .NET
>   Framework. Code loaded into this context can only be examined; it
>   cannot be executed. This means that objects cannot be created, because
>   constructors cannot be executed. Because the code cannot be executed,
>   dependencies are not automatically loaded. If you need to examine
>   them, you must load them yourself.

And in your code:

```
var obj = container.Resolve(ctrl);
```

You can't use `ctrl` type to do anything except just to examine it. You cannot create any objects which depends on it.